# Arrangement of buttons

Tags: android

I have created an array of buttons but all the buttons are arranged in vertical order.
I want 3 buttons in one row, next 3 buttons in second row and so on.

Here is my code please check it where it should be done.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.liLayout);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("" + i);
        b.setId(100 + i);
        b.setWidth(50);
        b.setHeight(20);
        layout.addView(b, p);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.main); 
//should have a vertical orientation
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liLayout); 

LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

LinearLayout rowLayout = null; **<--null will cause an exception**
*layout.addView(rowLayout)* **<--must be added to make sure the object/element exist/not null**

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) 
{
     if( (i % 3) == 1 ) 
     {
          rowLayout = new LinearLayout( this );
          layout.addView( rowLayout, p );
     }//if
     Button b = new Button(this);
     b.setText(""+ i);
     b.setId(100+i);
     b.setWidth(50);
     b.setHeight(20);
     rowLayout.addView(b, p); **<-- you can't add to rowLayout at first, because it doesn't exist yet**
}
```

}

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: hi stephane..the statements rowLayout=new LinearLayout(); gives an compilation error.."The constructor LinearLayout is not defined" and when i give rowLayout=new LinearLayout(null) its working..but gives runtime error

Comment: hey stephane..what should i do for make the buttons fill the screen horizontally, (and all be equally sized),becoz above all buttons i have textbox..so how can i integrate all this so that all of them fill the screen horizontally

Comment: @Anshuman the first thing to do would be to accept my answer. :) The second would be to give a weight of toe all 3 buttons b.setWeight(1) inside their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Copy, paste, enjoy..

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:text="Button1"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1" 
        android:text="Button2"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2" 
        android:text="Button3"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"  
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button4"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button5" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"  
        android:text="Button5"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"  
        android:text="Button6"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"  
        android:text="Button7"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"  
        android:text="Button8"/>


<Button android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6"
        android:text="Button9"/>
```

and read this:[Android Layout Tricks #1](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/)

Comment: suppose i had to crate create 100 buttons..than what should i do..simply adding 100 of buutons like this..think if i nedd 1000 of buttons.

Comment: well... i would populate them inside a grid view.

Comment: for all 1000 buttons..thats not efficient for a developer